# Jira using rest API - doing request with Anypoint Studio

Tags: jira, mule-studio, jira-rest-api, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I'm trying doing request in Anypoint Studio for this url https://{myhost}/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}.

I'm using only basic auth via Postman and this call doesn't work in Anypoint Studio.
I have this error:
HTTP GET on resource 'https://{myhost}:443/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}' failed: unauthorized (401)

When I use this url only using POSTMAN is working. But in Anypoint studio doesn't.

Could you help me?

Comment: Please share the HTTP request and its configuration in your question, as text XML, and also the equivalent HTTP Request from Postman using the Code link, as HTTP request. Kindly use text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details of the configurations I'll assume that the HTTP Request is missing the Basic Authentication configuration, or that the request didn't replace the URI parameters in the URL correctly.

You can configure Basic Authentication in the HTTP Request configuration. Example:

```
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" >
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="myhost" port="443" >
            <http:authentication >
                <http:basic-authentication username="myuser" password="mypassword" />
            </http:authentication>
        </http:request-connection>
    </http:request-config>
```

If the URI parameter is not correctly replaced JIRA may consider that you don't have access. Be sure to configure it correctly. Example:

```
<http:request method="GET" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}">
            <http:uri-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
   ---
   {
       "issueIdOrKey" : "1234"
   }]]]></http:uri-params>
</http:request>
```